# Count unique combinations of elements taken from different sets, and with fixed combination length

Tags: combinatorics

I have $n$ sets of numbers each containing  repeated number $x_n$, for instance I can have the following sets:

$$ \{1,1,1\}, \{3,3\}, \{8\}$$

where $n =3$, and $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 1$.

I would like to find the number of combination of length $z$ that starts with a given elements.

For example if I wanted to know the number of combinations that starts with $1$ and has length of $2$, then I would say $3$: $11,13,18$.

---

What I tried up until now was to consider the $3$ sets as one set, and try to find the number of combinations of length $z$ from this newly created set. It seemed simpler to formulate the problem as such because it means we lock the first element and for the rest of the elements we have count(elements)-1 possibilities then count(elements)-2 etc,for example if the required length is three and I have the same sets I would have $1 \cdot (9-1) \cdot (9 -2)$.

The issue with this is that I have a lots of duplicates that I didn't know how to remove, which gives the wrong result.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but solving exercises for you doesn't help anyone. Also, I don't see any computational aspect to this question.

Comment: what i tried up until now was to consider the 3 sets as one set, and try to find the number of combinations of length z from this newly created set. it seemed simpler to formulate the problem as such because it means we lock the first element and for the rest of the elements we have count(elements)-1 possibilies  then count(elements)-2 etc,for example if the required length is three and i  have the same sets i would have 1 * (9-1) * (9 -2),  the issue with this is that i have a lots of duplicate that i didn't know how to remove, which gives the wrong result